# How does a useEffect know to listen to a state variable?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state, react-state

```
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(1);
  
  useEffect(() => {}, [selected])
```

Since selected is just 1, why isn't the `useEffect` above equivalent to:

```
  useEffect(() => {}, [1])
```

Comment: because if the ```selected``` variable changes, your second example won't execute the code inside the ```useEffect```

Comment: It is just 1. Next render if you pass it 2, it will retrigger the effect. If you pass it 1 again, it won't.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in the first example, when `selected` changes the effect re-runs. In your second example, you've put a hard-coded value in the deps array (that's never going to change), so the effect will never run again after the first component mount.

So to answer your question:

- With example 1 you are saying: I expect this `selected` state to change at some point, when that happens re-run the effect.
- With example 2 you are saying: the deps never change, don't re-run the effect. In this case, you should just leave the deps array empty, which has the same effect and it's cleaner.